# How can I use JQuery getJSON to verify usernames

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have followed the tutorial found [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513001144/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022311-1.aspx) to get the basic understanding of what the title says. So far, I have come to the conclusion that the `$.getJSON` simply isnt working.

I have withered my code down to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var usernameUnavailableRow = $('#usernameUnavailableRow');
            var availabilityMessage = $('#availabilityMessage');

            $("#UserName").hover(function () {
                //usernameUnavailableRow.hide();
            });

            $("#UserName").blur(function () {
            $.getJSON('/OCDB/UsernameAvailable.aspx?' + escape($(this).val()), function (results) {
                if (results.available) {
                    alert("available"); //Just checking if anything even returns
                } else {
                    alert("not available"); //Just checking if anything even returns
                }
            });
        });
        });
    </script>

<table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <input id="UserName"></input>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="usernameUnavailableRow">
            <td>
               <span id="availabilityMessage">k</span>
            </td>
         </tr>
</table>
```

And my `UsernameAvailable.aspx` page shows exactly this:
`{ "available" : "false"}`
While Using
`<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="UsernameAvailable.aspx.cs" Inherits="UsernameAvailable" ContentType="application/json" %>`

Yet nothing is happening in the `getJson` event.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong, as I am unable to see my mistake.

**EDIT**
Upon changing the code to remove the 404 error the Javascript produced (Thanks @Archer), the result now always returns `True`. I have checked to see the page was returning `False` on a taken username, and it works.

Comment: What is the content type of UsernameAvailable.aspx? Is it a normal asp.net page or is it returning a JSON object?

Comment: Do you see anything in the console in your browser?  If the call is being made then you should be able to see if it's successful or not, and what is being returned.

Comment: @Archer - I overlooked that console COMPLETELY! Agh im an idiot :/ So for the update, the alert happens, but on both the available and unavailable, the alert always just shows available.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overlooked this line on that link:

> The UsernameAvailable.aspx page expects the desired username to be
>   supplied in the querystring, like so:
>   UsernameAvailable.aspx?*desiredUsername*.

You need to do this:

```
$.getJSON('UsernameAvailable.aspx?' + escape($(this).val()), function (results){
    if (results.available) {
        // available
    }
    else{
        // unavailable
    }
});
```

Comment: I removed it for simplicity in my code. While it was there before, i removed it because I thought it wasnt **needed** for this test. Will add and check. EDIT: Still not working.

Comment: From what @Archers said, and adding this bit of code to the mix, I have gotten the result, but unfortunatly the result is always `True`, even when the name is taken. When I pass the username variable to the url, the page responds with false, so that works.

Answer (score 0):

Is it `results` or `item` in `alert(item);` (Please check your code once again)

Also if you get a valid `json` then it will shown in `alert`,
 in alert it will show an `object` only. 
So to test it you need to write `console.log(results);` in place of `alert(item);`

One more thing that you can write `<input id="UserName"/>` in place of `<input id="UserName"></input>`

Comment: Sorry, its Results. I changed it just to a normal `"test"` string, but still a failure.

Comment: You can use `$.ajax` for this and check is it working or not For egs `$.ajax({dataType: "json",url: url,data: data,success: success});` Reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/